# Model.extend fails to update Collections. Backbone.js bug

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm building a responsive web framework, the architecture is all based around Backbone.js.
The plan is for it to eventually go open source, and for outside developers to be able to modify and edit methods on models. When writing a provisional plugin, I noticed that my methods were not being overridden.

After debugging, I realised that this was because when setting the model property in a collection, it wasn't a pointer to the constructor but a direct reference to the constructor at the time of the collection being defined. So far I have managed to patch this by extending the Collection's model attribute (with exactly the same data as before) immediately after the model has been extended. This seems like a general flaw within Backbone, or am I using it wrong.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.set("type", "original");
    }
})

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel
})

MyModel = MyModel.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.set("type", "modified");
    }
})

var test = new MyCollection();
test.add({type:null})
test.at(0).get("type") // original

MyCollection = MyCollection.extend({
    model: MyModel
})

var test2 = new MyCollection();
test2.add({type:null})
test2.at(0).get("type") // modified
```

It seems kinda wrong/superfluous for an outside developer to redefine the model attribute of any Collection that holds the type of Model they've overwritten.

Any ideas or workarounds would be appreciated. Or is this a genuine flaw?
I've included a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S4pcW/1/ , I'm not sure how much help that is as it's just code however if you copy and paste it into chrome developer tools whilst on backbonejs.org you should see what I mean.

Thanks in advance, any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: The above code doesn't make sense, you're trying to retrieve a model attribute with the collection's `get` method. `test.get("type")` will always return `undefined`.

Comment: that's true, my mistake, the js fiddle however is correct code, and the bug i was referring too is also still an issue. I have amended it to reflect this

Comment: It's really not a bug, there's nothing not working as it shouldn't. And your fiddle isn't testing what you claim to be the problem. I [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creynders/S4pcW/3/) and as you can see the collection does use the updated version of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I have since solved the issue and written a small plugin for this functionality.

https://github.com/allouis/backbone.dynamicCollections